# Keycode for dead_acute in VMWare

Tags: vmware-player

I installed VMWare Player on RedHat 6 and my German keyboard does not work correctly. I figured out how to solve AltGr problems with the help of this post
[several keyboard keys not working in vmware host linux guest windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/18067/several-keyboard-keys-not-working-in-vmware-host-linux-guest-windows)

However, I can't find the v-scan-code for dead acute. Is there such a code?